# How can i open another terminal in Whack Whack terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, cd

I'm trying to support two web applications on the same IDE (Visual Studio ) but not sure how can i have two terminals open. I would appreciate your help thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright just so that if anyone comes across this block, they can get to know my experience.

I'm building a chat application using React and Socket.io and I'm using Visual Studio (IDE different than Visual Studio Code (text editor)). In order to run the react application and the server together I needed two terminals open at the same time to invoke functions(send messages) within the application and listen on the server for a response.

### **How I was able to do it**

I already had the Whack Whack Terminal Extension downloaded and running and then i used the **Developer Command Prompt** where you can access in **Tools/Command Line/Developer Command Prompt.**

I hope this might come helpful to anyone who comes across this!